# Can the DataStax OpsCenter be used to monitor a Cassandra community edition cluster?

Tags: cassandra-2.0, datastax

I am trying to find the answer to this on the datastax website but are not able to do so. Can the Ops Center:

https://academy.datastax.com/downloads/ops-center#opsCenter

be used with the Cassandra community edition or it is only for Datastax Enterprise users?

I am asking because when I tried to install the Ops Center on my ubuntu which is also a Cassandra node it says that it will drain my Cassandra node and upgrade my installation to version 5.2.0.2015071411, which does not make sense. I am running Cassandra 2.20. Is it trying to upgrade me to a Datastax Enterprise behind the scenes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> be used with the Cassandra community edition or it is only for
>   Datastax Enterprise users?

**Yes, OpsCenter can be used to monitor OSS C* instances** though a few of the advanced features will be grayed out (repair service, backup service, performance service)

> Is it trying to upgrade me to a Datastax Enterprise behind the
>   scenes?

**No**, 5.2 is an OpsCenter version not a Cassandra version. OpsCenter will not upgrade your instance without telling you, though it may upgrade / install the datastax-agent which runs on every c* node and reports statistics for OpsCenter.

UPDATE: From OpsCenter 6.0 (newly releaesed) it will support only for enterprise edition

Comment: Whether still OpsCenter can be used to monitor OSS C* version like Cassandra 2.1.0? In [latest documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/5.2/opsc/opscPolicyChanges.html) I found `OpsCenter will only be compatible with DataStax Enterprise (DSE) cluster`. My understanding is, from OpsCenter 6.0 (still not yet releaesed) it will support only for enterprise edition. If I am using OpsCenter 5.2 then I can still use it for Cassaandra 2.1.0 but some features will be greyed. Whether my understanding is correct? Correct me if I am wrong